# Create text file without BOM google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, byte-order-mark, createfile

I am trying to create a text file in Google Drive that will be read by another program for automation. However, if I create the text file by Google Script the text will have BOM, which make automation quite unreliable.
I am currently using

```
var textFile = jobFolder.createFile(aFileName, fileContent,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
var textFile = jobFolder.createFile(aFileName, fileContent)
```

What's the way to create text file without BOM with Google App Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the BOM data of UTF-8, `EF BB BF` is added to the top of data. In this case, I think that to remove the top 3 bytes is to achieve your goal. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var textFile = jobFolder.createFile(aFileName, fileContent,MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT)
```

#### To:

```
var [,,,...newData] = Utilities.newBlob(fileContent).getBytes();
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(newData, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT, aFileName);
var textFile = jobFolder.createFile(blob);
```

- In this modification, it supposes that `fileContent` is the text data of BOM. Please be careful this.
- In this case, please declare the values of `aFileName` and `jobFolder`. Please be careful this.
- In this modified script, `newData` is the data that the top 3 bytes are removed.

#### Note:

- When your data of `fileContent` is not UTF-8, please check the wiki of [Byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). From this wiki, the top characters can be confirmed.

#### References:

- [Byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
- [newBlob(data, contentType, name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata,-contenttype,-name)
- [createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob)

### Added:

From your following replying,

> I have error on this line var [,,,...newData] = Utilities.newBlob(fileContent).getBytes();. Maybe because my Google App Script is the older version. What can I try for this?

I understood that you are not using V8 runtime. In this case, how about the following script?

#### Sample script:

```
var newData = Utilities.newBlob(fileContent).getBytes();
newData.splice(0, 3);
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(newData, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT, aFileName);
var textFile = jobFolder.createFile(blob);
```

Comment: I have error on this line `var [,,,...newData] = Utilities.newBlob(fileContent).getBytes();`. Maybe because my Google App Script is the older version. What can I try for this?

Comment: @Tam Le Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I couldn't notice that you are not using V8 runtime. I deeply apologize for this. For your situation without using V8 runtime, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: I just tested and confirmed this method of create file from blob indeed does not add BOM. My `fileContent` doesn't have BOM, it's just Google add it when create file in `DriveApp.createFile`. So the `newData.splice(0,3)` is not necessary.