# Importing .csv content from gmail into gsheet - script works - content shows strange symbols

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, gmail

when running my script to import .csv content from gmail it works and runs fine without any errors. But the content within the sheet is off. Strange thing is same script for other files works without problems - so I am wondering what is causing it. I checked the .csv and it is actually separated by semi colons (;) and structure wise it is exactly same as other .csvs where the script works fine. So I am really puzzled as why its not working, and it is every file from this person that I get daily that this doesnt work with.

```
  var threads = GmailApp.search('from:xyz@gmail.com subject:xyz');
  var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
  var file = messages[0].getAttachments()[0];
  var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getDataAsString(), ";");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  sh0.clearContents();
  sh0.getRange(1, 1, contents.length, contents[0].length).setValues(contents);
```

[This is what it looks like after the script ran successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w4LK.png)

[Similar thing with another file in another sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1387n.png)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Kind regards

EDIT*:

Used belows formula. Unfortunately this only reduced the amount of symbols in the sheet.

(Compare it to above pictures)

If I increase the slicer to be more than the symbols I get following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

*EDIT2:

Console log shows the same symbol as in screenshot. Here is the file: https://file.io/uh9thiY0ZKko

[First as above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xrKK.png)
[Removed onyl few symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4auJi.png)

Comment: As a guess. Perhaps it somehow has to do with the 'UTF8 with BOM' encoding. These mystic first three characters... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66816564/create-text-file-without-bom-google-apps-script You can try to skip the first three letters this way: `var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getDataAsString().slice(3), ";");`

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915684/parse-utf-8-bom-xml-files-using-xmlservice-google-app-script

Comment: Unfortunately this only reduced the amount of symbols in the sheet. :/

If I increase the slicer to be more than the symbols I get following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: The next obvious suspected is a particular JSON file. There are many characters in the wild that could cause such errors. If you share one of the problem JSON files I can try to figure out if there is something wrong inside.

Comment: Hmmm... How can I retrieve the JSON file?

Comment: As far as I can tell you have the mail with the attachment file. The attachment is likely the JSON file, I suppose. The next option is to add the line `console.log(contents)` into your code and get the contents in console. Probably something interesting will be there as well.

Comment: See my answer above in Edit 2

Comment: The CSV file uses semi-colons `;` and commas `,` as separators at the same time. No wonder if it's impossible to parse. And it contains 115 lines with data and 100 000+ empty lines (with semicolons and commas). Looks like something went terribly wrong when this file was generated. I see no way to fix this file even manually, not to mention to do it with a script.

Comment: Very interesting. But how come it is opening properly and without problems when opening it with excel or gsheets? Separator should always be ; all the , are part of the text in the fields

Comment: Unfortunately I rewrote your original file. But I remember these 100 000 lines that look like `;;;;,,` -- several semicolons and two comas at the end. Do you mean it's okay? Probably Excel and GSheet able to fix it, but obviously the parser `Utilities.parseCsv()` have no such ability. It makes sense to examine how this csv file was made. There was something wrong at that end.